# The specified value cannot be parsed, or is out of range when using number pipe

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

> The specified value cannot be parsed, or is out of range

When I get my object I format a number with a pipe but it returns this warning and the value isn't displayed. If I remove it, it is displayed.

This doesn't displays the value

```
  <input name="value" [ngModel]="value | number : '1.2-2'"/>
```

This displays the value

```
  <input name="value" [ngModel]="value"/>
```

TS
Here I get my object by its id after choosing it in a list.

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.get();
  }

get() {
    this.service.get(this.id).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.object = data;
        this.name = this.object.name;
        this.value = this.object.value;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

The value is a number and I get it in the console without any problem.

Comment: Well I've run out of answers. It'd be the bes if you could create an stackblitz with a demonstration of the problem. Even if i put "car" into the number pipe, i get a different error.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
<input [value]="units * 600 + 2500 | number" readonly type="text" name="grandtotal"
class="form-control" id="grandtotal" placeholder="Grand Total">
```

**I found my solution here changing or replacing the type in the HTML type="text"**

Comment: I really do not see how this is the solution.  What if my backend expects the value to be of type integer?

Comment: It's for the viewing of the data you can format it again before sending the data to the backend. :)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, my last take on this. I now understood what your question is. I did not read the title, just looked at your code.

The problem is in your `value`. In order for the value to be used with number pipe it has to be `Number` or a `string` but in a parse-able format. When the `value` is transformed in the number pipe, it is first parse to `Number`. If it is not parse-able, then you get the error you get.

You may be using a comma as a decimal separator which is not supported.

`"1,34"` is incorrect. `"1.34"` is correct.

If I am to help you further, I'd need to know what is the value of the `data.value`

Comment: data.value displays 0.02 and when I do a console log of the object it is a string.

Answer (score 2):

Just bind to `value` instead of `ngModel`. It is not needed.

```
<input name="value" [value]="value | number : '1.2-2'"/>
```

[Minimalist Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-msrfmc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: It still doesn't display the value, am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you using OnPush change detection strategy?

Comment: I use it on init.

Comment: Hi all - I have a similar issue.  Using "autocomplete" on a common `<input type='number' id="phoneNumber" maxlength=10 ...> - user had previously entered `+12025551212`, so that pops up when the field comes in focus, if the user selects that, the `+` causes the same error as in the OP, as well, the length is 12, two over the maxlength of the field.  Is there anyway way to capture the autocomplete entry to parse out the '+1' ???

Comment: Don't use `type=number` for phone numbers. Treat them as a string. Change `name` to avoid autocomplete collision.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `ngModel` but with the `OnPush` strategy.

When doing async work, you need to notify the change detector that your data has changed.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

get() {
    this.service.get(this.id).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.object = data;
        this.name = this.object.name;
        this.value = this.object.value;
        // notify the cd here
        this.cd.markForCheck();
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: The same thing happens when I add the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation, you might as well check the pipe number arguments:

1.2-2 = {minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}

where:

minIntegerDigits: The minimum number of integer digits before the decimal point. Default is 1.

minFractionDigits: The minimum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 0.

maxFractionDigits: The maximum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the value from html as any and then use parseFloat or parseInt

This works for me:

```
 let importeLuz = parseFloat(valor.importe as any);

       console.log(typeof(importeLuz)) //number
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I took the input as type="text" and then converted it into float using parseFloat() method in js.

`'longitude': parseFloat(e.target.longitude.value), 'latitude':parseFloat(e.target.latitude.value),`